# How to add LTspice boundary condition?

Tags: ltspice, simulation, spice

I have this circuit in LTspice:

[image]

I want to add a boundary condition: the voltage is 3.30 V at the time \$t=20\ \mu\text{s}\$.

I have an example, but I can't remember how I did it last time:

[image]

Comment: What do you want that boundary to do?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I want 3 graphs of voltage, power and energy versus time. Either that or a function of the voltage.

Comment: You asked about a boundary condition. What are you talking about?

Comment: You can set the voltage at time 0 like you did with your .ic card. Now just imagine that was actually t=20 us, and offset all your other times to compensate.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen sorry! I meant i want to write the boundary condition in the circuit, exactly like the second picture. In the 2nd picture, the circuit ran with the boundary condition v(vc)=0. Like that, but with v(20 mu*s)=3.3 V

Comment: @ThePhoton Best make it an answer, I don't trust my translator right now.

Comment: @yikes, Do you want to simulate the time before the voltage reaches 3.3 V or after?

Comment: @ThePhoton before.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify. Also, consider that your instructor may have deliberately given you a problem that requires you to answer analytically rather than use a simulator to solve it.